# TFF: How define tff.simulation.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn Function?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

In the federated learning context, One such classmethod that should work would be tff.simulation.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn. Here, if I pass a list of client_ids and a function which returns the appropriate dataset when given a client id, you will have your hands on a fully functional ClientData.

I think here, an approach for defining the function I may use is to construct a Python dict which maps client IDs to tf.data.Dataset objects--you could then define a function which takes a client id, looks up the dataset in the dict, and returns the dataset.
So I define function as below but I think it is wrong, what do you think?

```
list = ["0","1","2"]
tab = {"0":ds, "1":ds, "2":ds}
def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(id):
    return ds

source = tff.simulation.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(list, create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn)
```

I suppose here that the 4 clients have the same dataset :'ds'

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `dict` of `(client_id, dataset)` key-value pairs is a reasonable way to set up a `tff.simulation.ClientData`. Indeed, the code in the question will result in all clients have the same dataset since `ds` is return for all values of parameter `id`. One thing to watch out in pre-constructing a `dict` of datasets is that it may require loading the entire contents of the data into memory (may fail for large datasets).

Alternatively, constructing the dataset on-demand could reduce memory usage. One example might be to have a `dict` of `(client_id, file path)` key-value pairs. Something like:

```py
dataset_paths = {
  'client_0': '/tmp/A.txt',
  'client_1': '/tmp/B.txt',
  'client_2': '/tmp/C.txt',
}

def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(id):
   path = dataset_paths.get(id)
   if path is None:
     raise ValueError(f'No dataset for client {id}')
   return tf.data.Dataset.TextLineDataset(path)

source = tff.simulation.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(
  dataset_paths.keys(), create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn)
```

This is similar to the approach used in [`tff.simulation.FilePerUserClientData`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/FilePerUserClientData#class_fileperuserclientdata). It may be useful to look at the code of that class as an example.

Comment: Thank you very much .. Good solution