# tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData to build federated learning model from CSV files

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am building a federated learning model using my own dataset.
I aim to build a multi classification model.
The data are presented in separate 8 CSV files.

I followed the instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60265798/tff-how-define-tff-simulation-clientdata-from-clients-and-fn-function) As shown in the code below.

```
dataset_paths = {
  'client_0': '/content/ds1.csv',
  'client_1': '/content/ds2.csv',
  'client_2': '/content/ds3.csv',
  'client_3': '/content/ds4.csv',
  'client_4': '/content/ds5.csv',
}

def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(id):
   path = dataset_paths.get(id)
   if path is None:
     raise ValueError(f'No dataset for client {id}')
   return tf.data.Dataset.TextLineDataset(path)

source = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(
  dataset_paths.keys(), create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn)
```

but it gave me this error

```
AttributeError: type object 'ClientData' has no attribute 'from_clients_and_fn'
```

I was reading this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/ClientData#datasets) and found that `.datasets` methods would work, so I replaced with `.from_clients_and_fn` and the error disappeared but I dont know if it is right and what is next?

My questions are:

1. it this is a right method to upload the data to the clients?
2. if it is not possible to upload the CSV files separately, can I combine all of the data into one CSV file and then consider them as a non-IID data and train them accordingly?
   I need some guidance here

and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this setup it maybe useful to consider [`tff.simulation.datasets.FilePerUserClientData`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/FilePerUserClientData) and [`tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset).

This might look like (this makes some test CSV data for the sake of the example, the dataset your working with likely has other shapes):

```py
dataset_paths = {
  'client_0': '/content/ds1.csv',
  'client_1': '/content/ds2.csv',
  'client_2': '/content/ds3.csv',
  'client_3': '/content/ds4.csv',
  'client_4': '/content/ds5.csv',
}

# Create some test data for the sake of the example,
# normally we wouldn't do this.
for i, (id, path) in enumerate(dataset_paths.items()):
  with open(path, 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(i):
      f.write(f'test,0.0,{i}\n')

# Values that will fill in any CSV cell if its missing,
# must match the dtypes above.
record_defaults = ['', 0.0, 0]

@tf.function
def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(dataset_path):
   return tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
     dataset_path, record_defaults=record_defaults )

source = tff.simulation.datasets.FilePerUserClientData(
  dataset_paths, create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn)


print(source.client_ids)
>>> ['client_0', 'client_1', 'client_2', 'client_3', 'client_4']

for x in source.create_tf_dataset_for_client('client_3'):
  print(x)
>>> (<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'test'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>)
>>> (<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'test'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>)
>>> (<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'test'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>)
```

It may be possible to concatenate all the data into a single CSV, but each record would still need some identifier indicating which row belongs to which client. Mixing all the rows together without any kind of per-client mapping would be akin to standard centralized training, not federated learning.

Once a CSV has all the rows, and perhaps a column with a `client_id` value, one could presumably use [`tf.data.Dataset.filter()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter) to only yield the rows belonging to a particular client. This probably won't be particularly efficient though, as it would iterate over the entire global dataset for each client, rather than only that client's examples.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, I choose to follow the first approach (using each file as a single client) 
1) I want to ask, since I will build a supervised learning model, how can I select the `features` columns and `label` column?
2) How can I split the data into training and testing? 
3) how can I select the local ML model for each client?